# Bundler error: Retrying git cat-file ... If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory

Tags: git, bundler

I did bundle update zipcar which is a local gem and got:

```
$ bundle update zipcar
Retrying git cat-file -e 78c5245dd174058958a07d6674de7bc037e14ed5 due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git
 error: command `git cat-file -e 78c5245dd174058958a07d6674de7bc037e14ed5` in directory /Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/c
ache/bundler/git/tricorder-4921ab3158ace9efb6d757333e208c58cbfe3e2e has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/cache/bundler/git/tric
order-4921ab3158ace9efb6d757333e208c58cbfe3e2e'
Retrying git cat-file -e 78c5245dd174058958a07d6674de7bc037e14ed5 due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git
 error: command `git cat-file -e 78c5245dd174058958a07d6674de7bc037e14ed5` in directory /Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/c
ache/bundler/git/tricorder-4921ab3158ace9efb6d757333e208c58cbfe3e2e has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/cache/bundler/git/tric
order-4921ab3158ace9efb6d757333e208c58cbfe3e2e'
```

Answer (score 2):

It was due to a feature of bundler detecting a network glitch.

The simple fix for me was to just run it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a similar error if you did a rebase on gem code.  For example, if you have something like this in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mygemname', :git => 'https://github.com/foo/mygemname.git'
```

It puts something like this in your `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/foo/mygemname.git
  revision: aaabbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccdddddxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The error you'll see in the Heroku logs looks something like:

```
Retrying git cat-file -e aaabbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccdddddxxxxxxxxxxxx due 
to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: 
command `git cat-file -e aaabbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccdddddxxxxxxxxxxxx` 
in directory /tmp/build_...
```

This is because the git hash changed during the rebase.  The solution is to remove the gem from your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install`, and then add it back again (which will use the new git hash).

Comment: This help me to fix a problem with capistrano.. I messed up revision codes with too much rebasing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the very similar problem. It resolved when I delete `gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again.